# If $A\ge 0$ and $A^k>0$ for some positive integer $k$ then $\rho (A) \ne 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Defin: We say $A \ge 0$ if all $a_{ij}\ge 0$.**

Now let $A\in M_n$ and  $A\ge 0$ and $A^k>0$ for some positive integer $k$.

Why does $\rho (A) \ne 0$?

Comment: Sorry, but my mindreading skills don't work over the internet. You will have to supply a definition for $\rho$ as well.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  - $\rho (A) = \max \left\{ {\left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda  \in \sigma (A)} \right\}$ where ${\sigma (A)}$ is spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Note: an $A$ satisfying $A^k > 0$ for some $k$ is said to be *ergodic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perron-Frobeinius theorem says, among other things, than any $B>0$ will have an eigenvalue $\mu > 0$ (in fact, you may simply have this statement as a theorem on its own).

So, $A^k$ must have an eigenvalue $\mu > 0$, which means that $A$ must have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^k = \mu$.  Since $\lambda \neq 0$, $\rho(A) \neq 0$.